# Simple regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to simply get everything after the colon in the following:

```
hfarnsworth:204b319de6f41bbfdbcb28da724dda23
```

And then everything before the space in the following:

```
29ca0a80180e9346295920344d64d1ce ::: 25basement
```

Here's what I have:

```
for line in f: 
    line = line.rstrip() #to remove \n
    line = re.compile('.* ',line) #everything before space. 
    print line
```

Any tips to point me in the corrent direction? Thanks!

Also, is re.compile the correct function to use if I want the matched string returned? I'm pretty new at python too. 
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

```
string = "hfarnsworth:204b319de6f41bbfdbcb28da724dda23"
print(string.split(":")[1:])
string = "29ca0a80180e9346295920344d64d1ce ::: 25basement"
print(string.split(" ")[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

At first you should probably take a careful look at the doc for [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile).  It doesn't expect for second parameter to be a string to lookup.  Try to use `re.search` or `re.findall`. E.g.:

```
>>> s = "29ca0a80180e9346295920344d64d1ce ::: 25basement"
>>> re.findall('(\S*) ', s)[0]
'29ca0a80180e9346295920344d64d1ce'
>>> re.search('(\S*) ', s).groups()
('29ca0a80180e9346295920344d64d1ce',)
```

BTW, this is not the task for regular expressions.  Consider using some simple string operations (like `split`).

Answer (score 0):

this regular expression seems to work

```
r"^(?:[^:]*\:)?([^:]*)(?::::.*)?$"
```